# Typescript - conditional return type based on optional properties of a parameter

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make an index.d.ts for my javascript file.

I've got a function:

```
function characters(query, options)
```

where `options` is an optional object that has optional properties that can change the return type of the function.

So far this is what I've written:

```
export const characters: QueryFunction<Character>;

export interface QueryFunction<Result> {
    // retrieve list of names
    (query: "names", opts?: { matchCategories: true; } ): string[];
    (query: "names", opts?: { matchCategories: true; verboseCategories: true; } ): Result[];

    // match single result
    (query: string, opts?: { matchCategories: false | undefined; } ): Result | undefined;

    // may return multiple results
    (query: string, opts?: { matchCategories: true; } ): Result | string[] | undefined;
    (query: string, opts?: { matchCategories: true; verboseCategories: true; } ): Result | Result[] | undefined;
}

export interface QueryOptions {
    matchAliases?: boolean;  // default true
    matchCategories?: boolean;  // default false
    verboseCategories?: boolean;  // default false
}
```

I'm not sure how to extend opts to use QueryOptions or take into account undefined properties.

Comment: Could you explain in words and/or provide code that demonstrates exactly *how* you want to take into account undefined options?  I'm not quite following.  If I ignore `matchAliases` because it doesn't seem to be referenced at all in your `QueryFunction` definition, and if I try to figure out the general pattern, it looks like it might be [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nn61xN).  But without seeing a bunch of use cases, like calls and expected outcomes, that's just a guess.  A [mcve] goes a long way to getting a good answer.

Comment: Yeah sorry it was my first time trying to make interfaces for typescript and I had trouble wording my question. Actually your code is pretty much what I wanted it to be. The Playground is very useful for figuring out the calculated return type. Thank you so much for the help!